# Page Break not working with ngFor in Angular 13

Tags: angular, printing, ngx-bootstrap, angular-template

I've done some searching around for a solution, but page breaks in an Angular 13 component will not break pages.

I am using a simple ng-template (extra fields removed for readability):

```
<ng-template #testTemplate let-allTheData>
  <div *ngFor="let dataItem of allTheData" >
    <div><b>ID:</b> {{ dataItem.id }}</div>
    <div style="break-after:always;">&nbsp;</div>  <-- non-working page break
  </div>
```

The template is setup as a ViewChild like this:

```
@ViewChild('testTemplate ') testTemplate !: TemplateRef<any>;
```

The data gets passed in and processed through a loop

```
 data.forEach(x => {
      theThing = {};
      theThing.id = arrtId;
      this.theData.push(theThing);
    });
```

And the print dialog gets called with this line (using ngx-print):

```
this.printer.printAngular(this.testTemplate);
```

The data shows up fine on the print screen, but the page break in the template does not insert a page break - is the template interfering?  I've also tried "break-after: page," "break-after: auto" and even "break-before: page," "break-before: auto" and "break-before: always." I also tried using the CSS media queries I've seen in a few searches and adding "!Important" to the inline CSS. Nothing has yet worked. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing the css syntax is a bit off `page-break-after: always`.

```html
  <div style="page-break-after: always" *ngFor="let dataItem of allTheData" >
    <div><b>ID:</b> {{ dataItem.id }}</div>
  </div>

  <button (click)="onPrint()">Print</button>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  allTheData = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
  constructor() {}

  onPrint() {
    window.print();
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9wgfdt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Sorry, I should have been clearer what's different in my example. I'll improve my comment. If you have applied the correct css syntax then move `#testTemplate` away from `<ng-template>` to a `<div>`, for example. `ng-template` does not get rendered in template, so you have nothing to reference. Then call `this.printer.printAngular(this.testTemplate);` in `ngAfterViewInit()`. `<div>` with  `#testTemplate`  becomes available earliest in this cycle.

```html
<ng-template let-allTheData>
  <div #testTemplate 
       style="page-break-after: always"
       *ngFor="let dataItem of allTheData">
    <div><b>ID:</b> {{ dataItem.id }}</div>
  </div>
```

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.printer.printAngular(this.testTemplate);
}
```

Comment: This does definitely work, but I'm also trying use an Angular template and ngx-printer and the page breaks aren't showing up with that configuration. If I don't make any progress there, maybe I need to revisit the approach, but thanks for your reply

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer what's different in my example. I'll improve my comment. If you have applied the correct css syntax then move `#testTemplate` away from `<ng-template>` to a `<div>`, for example. `ng-template` does not get rendered in template, so you have nothing to reference. Then call `this.printer.printAngular(this.testTemplate);` in `ngAfterViewInit()`. `<div>` with  `#testTemplate`  becomes available earliest in this cycle.

Comment: This ended up taking a very different turn - we were using ngx-printer and switched to ngx-print and everything worked fine, including the line breaks, with that library. So I didn't actually get a chance to try the solution you posted, but I'll mark it as best answer anyway. Thanks for all of your input.